# How to disable a link in sent email once the link is clicked

Tags: html, google-apps-script, web-applications, html-email

I have an app script code to send email that includes html body with href tags, this tags are to approve or reject the request. But once the approve link is clicked i get an email with approval details and if the approve link is clicked again then it must disable sending approval email again.

Here is my code tried and i want to disable this link once clicked and not to send email once the link is already clicked.

```
var options = '?approval=%APPROVE%&timestamp=%TIMESTAMP%&reply=%EMAIL%&last=%Last%&clicked=%CLICKED%'
         .replace("%TIMESTAMP%",encodeURIComponent(e.namedValues["Timestamp"]))
         .replace("%EMAIL%",e.namedValues["Email Address"]) 
         .replace("%Last%",last)
         .replace("%CLICKED%",clicked)       
  var approve = url+options.replace("%APPROVE%","Approved"); 
  var reject = url+options.replace("%APPROVE%","Rejected");

  var html = "<body>" +
    "Name : " + Name + "<br/>" +
    "Email id : " + email + "<br/>" +
    "Leave Type : " + leavetype + "<br/>" +
    "Reason : " + Reason + "<br/>" +
    "Start Date : " + start_date + "<br/>" +
    "End Date : " + end_date + "<br/>" +
    "<a href=" + approve + ">Approve</a><br />" +
    "<a href=" + reject + ">Reject</a><br />" +
    "</body>";

  MailApp.sendEmail("email",
                    "Leave Approval Request", 
                    "Requires html",
                    {htmlBody: html}); 

function doGet(e){
  var answer = (e.parameter.approval === 'Approved') ? 'Hi. Your Leave Request is APPROVED,    Please update the same in Calender. ' : 'Hi. Your Leave Request is REJECTED'; 
  
  var timestamp = e.parameter.timestamp;
  var last = e.parameter.last;
  var clicked = e.parameter.clicked;

  MailApp.sendEmail(e.parameter.reply, "Leave Request Status", 
                      answer );
```

Comment: so far with what you shared, all that could be said is flip the e.parameters.clicked value after checking if it's false to trigger the sendEmail. But you didn't share anything about the caller or where's the element to disable

Comment: Hi Diego, Thanks for responding, once the link is changed to clicked and even it remains the same in that sent email as the link will be clicked through email

Comment: you could do like maintain a table using a OTP with description and status. And when ever you send a mail add a otp to the table with proper description and status as active or true. And send the like with otp as parameter and perform task if status true else reject the request

Comment: Actually *nothing* can prevent the receiver from using the link multiple times; the *server* has to make sure that it cannot be re-used if it should not.

Comment: This can not be done at the email level. As U.Windl mentioned, you will have to do this at the server/page level.